# Protractor: Getting 'Failed: Unknown error' for test running in Edge Browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

My setup:

- Protractor Version: 5.3.0
- Edge Version: 38.14393.2068.0
- Edge HTML: 14.14393
- MicrosoftWebDriver.exe version: 10.0.14393.0
- Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit

Code:

```js
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:17556/',
    capabilities: {
      "browserName": "MicrosoftEdge",
      nativeEvents: false
    },
    framework: "jasmine2",
```

Steps I Follow (test count: ~200):

1. Launch MicrosoftWebDriver.exe manually or use command:

`webdriver-manager start --edge C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe`

2. Run the suite using protractor config setup after the test has ran for approx. 7 to 10 minutes, with total ~30 test cases ran, I get below error:

   `Failed: Unknown error WebDriverError: Unknown error`

After this error the protractor stalls for around 15 minutes before failing other tests with timeout (After unknown error there is no action on edge browser).

Steps taken to understand this error:

1. I started commenting out the tests in which I was getting ‘Unknown error’. but the error kept triggering for next one (totally random)
2. I tried running the tests individually in which I was getting ‘unknown error’ and they were running fine.

My understanding is that the MicrosoftWebDriver.exe stops working after a certain test, and then it doesn’t respond to the protractor.

Any help to resolve / understand this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the driver and browser version compatibility?